# What is the difference between statistical modelling and statistical downscaling?

Tags: distributions, modeling, prediction, model, climate

I have a confusion about the difference between statistical modeling and statistical downscaling in application and their properties and which one can be used accurately and easily for environmental application such that for precipitation or air pollution.

Statistical modeling is used for predication and estimate parameters, isn't it?Statistical downscaling is used to explain the relationship the large  scale climate and local scale  climate, isn't it? 
May someone explain to me please?

Comment: You should give details about the applications you are interested in. I have only ever heard about downscaling in the context of climate models (or otherwise large-scale weather models) where it means trying to find implications of the large-scale model for a specific geographical area, described on a denser grid. "What does global climate models imply for New York city"

Answer (score 0):

You should give details about the applications you are interested in.  I have only ever heard about downscaling in the context of climate models (or otherwise large-scale weather models) where it means trying to find implications of the large-scale model for a specific geographical area, described on a denser grid.  "What does global climate model predictions  imply for New York city"